# Contenttypes in Bolt CMS: How to change field used for listing in backend

Tags: content-management-system, twig, bolt-cms

I would like to change the field used for displaying in backend listings.
By default the first defined field is used, here it would be `title`

`news:
    name: News
    singular_name: Newsitem
    fields:
        title:
            type: text
            class: large
            height: 300px`

How can I change this? And it would be nice to combine fields to use for display, like `displayfield: {date|title}`
that could be shown like '2014-04-12 My News'

In frontend, I can use listing_template option. What about the backend? Do I have to change my bolt backend theme?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the "overview listing" twig template for each contenttype, if you wish. copy `app/view/twig/_sub/_listing.twig` to `app/view/twig/custom/listing/ [contenttype.slug] .twig`, and modify it to your needs.

Comment: thank you! So basically i could rewrite the whole backend views to my needs.